# OR-tools VRP with Multi-dimension. Optimize in one, constrains in others

Tags: or-tools

I have a problem when I want to optimize the global Cost of the vehicules' route. So for that I register a Cost Dimension for returning the cost associated to each arc. But at the same time I have restrictions in another dimensions such as Time & Distance. How can I achieve this? Maybe I just only have to use AddDimension for each callback, but I don't know how to set the Objective function in RoutingModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All in your question: Does restriction aka constraint should be part of the objective cost ? or this is just, well constraints the solver need to fulfill ?

Adding new dimension using AddDimension() is a good start IMHO.
note: You may also add the span or global span of any dimension to the objective cost by setting the corresponding coefficient (zero by default thus dimension won't participate to the objective cost and only add "constraint" to the solution)

ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b37d9c786b69128f3505f15beca09e89bf078a89/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L2482-L2496

Comment: Just the solver need to fulfill those constrains. They don't form part of the objective funtion. Thank you for the advise, it sounds that it could actually work. I'll try it.